# Picam and USB serial comms issue

Tags: usb, serial, pi-3b+, picamera

Are there any known issues with serial comms & the Picam module?

When I have a serial channel open (over USB) & write to it whilst viewing the input from a Picam on screen, the view port will freeze after about 10 seconds.

Using the same program with the serial writes commented out & eveything behaves.

**Edit** dont forget to flush your serial out buffer!

Comment: "*Using the same program ...*", what program?

Comment: @Ingo its was a simple video capture program, problem solved now

Comment: Could you please write an answer and explain in short what's the solution? This would finish your question and no one tries to help you (for nothing ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stemmed from an overflow in the serial buffer. Previously I had been using a web cam via the USB which must have been clearing the buffer under the hood so to speak, which was why I wasnt encountering the issue.

The Picam on the other hand has nothing to do with the USB hub, so the automatic buffer flushing wasnt taking place. I included `s1.flushInput()` after every batch of serial writes in my loops (where `s1 = serial.Serial(port, rate)`) and this solved the problem.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.